# Configuring Log4Net for specific classes and overreaching error handling

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I am using Log4Net within my project, and would like to configure it so that debug/info messages go to files specific to each class, and all error messages go to a central file.

Within my application, I have several "workers".  I would like each worker to have its own log file to capture debug messages.  If I get a debug message that isn't captured on a specific worker, I would like it to be logged to a central debug file.  I would also like to have central error logging, where all errors from any of the workers are logged in the same file.

I am having difficulty figuring out the XML configuration to do this.
Here is the closest I have come:

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="DebugLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\debug.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="ddMMyyyy" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ErrorLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\error.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="ddMMyyyy" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline%stacktrace{1}%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="ERROR" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="Worker1" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\Worker1.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <datePattern value="ddMMyyyy" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="INFO" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="Worker2" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\Worker2.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <datePattern value="ddMMyyyy" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="INFO" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="Worker3" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\3.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <datePattern value="ddMMyyyy" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        <levelMax value="INFO" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="DebugLog" />
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorLog" />
    </root>
    <logger name="Worker1">
      <level value='DEBUG'/>
      <appender-ref ref="Worker1" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="Worker2">
      <level value='DEBUG'/>
      <appender-ref ref="Worker2" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="Worker3">
      <level value='DEBUG'/>
      <appender-ref ref="Worker3" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

The first issue I have is that all messages written to Worker1's class, are written to the Debug.log file, and the Worker1.log file.  I don't want them written to Debug.log if they are already written to Worker1.log.

I can get around this by changing the  section, by adding additivity = false.  In this case, it writes to the Worker1.log, and not the Debug.log file.

However, doing this prevents errors from being written to Error.log
What happens is that if I set additivity = "false" and log an error, it gets written to Worker1.log, but does not get written to Error.log.

Is there any way to have the additivity apply to just the debug/info messages, so that I can have Debug messages in Worker1.log, Error messages in Error.log, and any debug messages that aren't specific to a logger in the debug.log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about setting `additivity="false"` to isolate the `debug`  messages to `Worker1.log`.

To get the `error` messages of `Worker1` back into `Error.log` you also have to include the `ErrorLog` appender in the `Worker1` `logger` declaration, as shown below.

```
<logger name="Worker1" additivity="false">
    <level value='DEBUG'/>
    <appender-ref ref="Worker1" />
    <appender-ref ref="ErrorLog" />
</logger>
```

Via this setup you overrule the rules as defined in `root` to use a custom `Worker1` `Appender` for `debug` messages and the same `Error` `Appender`for `error` messages.